# heroku multiple subdomains with ssl possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, heroku, routes

I have this app on heroku the main part of it is called app.example.com for which I have custom domains on heroku, and added endpoint ssl to it. it's all working. By the way, the original www.example.com is very old, and it is hosted somewhere else not on Heroku.

On heroku, I just

```
heroku domains:add app.example.com
```

Now, we have an order form for user to order stuff before they get to use the app. and the client wants to have its url as order.example.com instead of app.example.com/order. I looked up routing constraint in Rails from RailsCasts to handle this subdomain redirect, so all's good. then I add it to heroku's custom domains

```
heroku domains:add order.example.com
```

then I change the CNAME on the original host of www.example.com to have it point order.example.com to myapps.herokuapps.com (or something). And now accessing order.example.com does bring me to the order form! Just that the https part is showing the usual non-verified cert warning.

So I went ahead and got myself another godaddy certificate, but now when I try to add the certificate to heroku (I have done this once before for app.example.com's https)

```
heroku certs:add ~/ssl/combined.crt ~/ssl/nopass.key
```

Adding SSL endpoint to order-dev... failed
 !    only one SSL endpoint allowed per app (try certs:update instead)

So it seems like I can't actually have more than one SSL certificate per app, does that mean I can actually use what I have for certificate for app.example.com for order.example.com also? If so, what do I have to configure? Or am I doing this all wrong, if so, what should I have done instead?

Thank you for helping out here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should buy wildcard certificate for *.example.com as opposed to multiple certs.